# Issue with Matplotlib scatterplot and Color maps

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot, colormap

I am working on a project that involves applying colormaps to scatterplots generated in matplotlib. My code works as expected, unless the scatterplot being generated has exactly four points. This is illustrated in the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow_r')

z = np.arange(20)
plt.close()
plt.figure(figsize=[8,6])

for i in range(1,11):
    x = np.arange(i)
    y = np.zeros(i) + i
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=cmap(i / 10), edgecolor='k', label=i, s=200)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This code generates the following plot:

[image: matplotlib plot]

Each row should consist of points of the same color, but that is not the case for the row with four points.

I assume it has to do with the fact that the color selected from the colormap is returned as a tuple of 4 floats, as illustrated below:

```
print(cmap(0.4))
>>  (0.69999999999999996, 0.95105651629515364, 0.58778525229247314, 1.0)
```

Assuming that this is the source of the issue, I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I played around a little with your code and basically you were on to the problem; the similar dimensions of the cmap values with the data caused them to be interpreted differently for the "4" case.

This seems to work correctly:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=[cmap(i / 10)], edgecolor='k', label=i, s=200)
```

(List constructor around return value from cmap)

[image: fixed_chart]

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is a common pitfall, such that [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) espectially mentions it:

> Note that `c` should not be a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence because that is indistinguishable from an array of values to be colormapped.

It also directly gives you the solution:

> `c` can be a 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA, however, including the case of a single row to specify the same color for all points.

In this case:

```
c=np.atleast_2d(cmap(i/10.))
```

---

A different option is of course to specify the color as a string such that this abiguity is resolved.

```
c = matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(cmap(i/10.))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the problem, and for the solution.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try out your solution until just now, and oddly, it doesn't work. I get exactly the same output as before. I also tried the solution below, and it didn't work either. :(

Comment: This is super hacky, but the only solution I could get to work was to create an array with two copies of the same color:


`c=[my_cmap(i / 10), my_cmap(i / 10)]`

Comment: Probably updating matplotlib would also help. I added a different option to the answer as well.

Comment: Thank you! The second option seems to have worked for me. Which is good, because, as I should have anticipated, my hacky solution above just shifted the problem to scatter plots with 8 points. 

Thanks again!