# Weird thing in seaborn and how to correct it

Tags: python, python-2.7, colors, seaborn

I'm using Python 2.7.15, seaborn 0.9.0 & matplotlib 2.0.2

When I try to plot 4 points with `seaborn scatterplot` function, there are all of different colors:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(x=range(4), y=[1]*4)
```

[image]

If I do the same with 3 or 5 points, there are all of the same color.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(x=range(5), y=[1]*5)
```

[image]

Does anyone know if there is a (good) reason for that or if it is a bug ?

But more important, what do I have to do in order to get the same color for all the 4 points ?

PS: I couldn't reproduce this in Python 3.7

Comment: I also cannot reproduce. You probably want to be more exact concerning the versions in use, specifically the matplotlib version will be relevant.

Comment: matplotlib 2.0.2 is too old for me to test this. I would recommend updating matplotlib to 2.2.3 or 2.2.4 (if you're on python2.7), else to the newest available version (on python 3)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have ran into this issue (which i have also just ran in to, with matplotlib 2.2.3), [Issue with Matplotlib scatterplot and Color maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872731/issue-with-matplotlib-scatterplot-and-color-maps)

What is likely happening is seaborn is specifying the colors as a 4 component RGBA value which matplotlib is then interpreting as being a separate color for each individual point, instead of one color for all points.